# How can I launch a application with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, whenever

I want to write a simple script that will check to see if a program is open every hour [using the whenever gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/whenever). If that application is not open I want it to start up the application. I can't find out how to launch an application with Ruby. Pardon the ignorance. I am new.

Comment: whenever just makes cronjobs. You need a script to do all the things you say, first. Scheduling it to run every hour is step 2. Try to make the script to check if an application is open, and running it "normally" first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run an application in various ways:

`Kernel#system` runs my_program in a subshell and returns `true` if the subshell exits successfully, `false` otherwise.

`system("my_program")`

`Kernel#exec` replaces the currently executing process with my_program.

`exec("my_program")`

`%x()` will run the program and return the output.

`%x(my_program)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Kernal#system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-system) method like this:

```
system 'open -n /Applications/Appname.app'
```

With `#system` you'll get a return value of true or false, enabling you to do some flow control incase there's an issue (i.e. maybe the app doesn't exist in the system)